# Trying to catch a particular ConstraintViolationException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, exception

Basic Info- I'm using Java 8 with Spring MVC 5.2 and Hibernate 5.4 (using Maven)

I have the following Data Object Class -

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TaskDetails", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint( columnNames = {"taskID", "processID"} )} )
public class TaskDetailsDo implements Serializable{
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="contextID")
    private String contextID;
    
    @Column(name="taskID")
    private String taskID;
    
    @Column(name="processID")
    private String processID;
```

(and a bunch of other columns but that is not relevant here as none of them have any constraints).

Now, in my Data Access Object class, I want to save an object only when the same combination of taskID and processID doesn't already exist. For that, I'm using

```
public boolean save(TaskDetailsDo taskDetails) {
        try {
            getSession().save(taskDetails);
            return true;
        } catch(ConstraintViolationException e)
            {
              return false;
            }
```

Now, the idea here is that if a combination already exists, it would throw a ConstraintViolationException and I would return false effectively conveying that a combination already exists. However, the problem is that ConstraintViolationException would also catch other types of Constraint Violations (maybe with the primary key, for example). Now, I only want to catch a particular type of ConstraintViolationException, i.e. one which was thrown due to Unique Constraint Violation. Is there any way to detect which constraint was violated?

Alternatively, is there another way to achieve the functionality that I'm looking for?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how the primary key is generated, maybe it's impossible that the primary key constraint is violated or the possibility is low,so you can always tell the combination  Constraint Violations.Or you can  query before save,or check the message of ConstraintViolationException whether contains `primary key` keyword or taskID or processID , the worst thing is you giving a wrong result that combination already exists while it's actually a primary key conflict

Comment: I'm generating the primary key. Yes, the possibility is low but it's still there.

Comment: @SanchitSnehashish you can probably use instancof operator for condition checking.Also you could try getCause method for the exception e.You can also use getConstraintName method to get which constraint failed.

Comment: as @sachin said, get the cause or exception message and check that. I think you would get "Unique index or primary key violation" in your message.